# ASP.NET MVC Session still active on Browser Close

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a asp.net mvc application with session state enabled (sqlSessionProvider). End user will need to log in to ASP.NET MVC Application.

Once loggedin and when end user closes the browser, the session is still active next time the end user comes back to website.

Could anyone tell me what is the best solution I should take to solve this problem, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Flybyte, you've asked 12 questions and never closed one. Since other people spend their time trying to help you, you should reward them.

Comment: Hi Lefty, as you may know I'm newbiew to StackOverflow. I'm not fully aware of all the rules. How do I close the questions and how do vote for the best?  SPent 30min yesterday trying to fig. out this.

Comment: Flybyte, if a user answered a question and you're satisfied about it just close it with the check symbol which appears next to the user's answer. You can use the arrows to up-vote or down-vote a good or a silly answer.I made the same mistake at the beginning, don't worry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are not destroyed by closing the browser window.
Take a look at: [session Handling in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5455840/337294) to find out more about the workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

My testing showed the it's only IE 8.0 that is not cleaning the session on browser close. Other browsers such as Safari and Firefox have no problem.

Comment: Don't add additional information in an "answer", edit your post to contain the additional information.  If you want to make it clear, you can add an "UPDATE" to the text to indicate you updated it.  Answers are for answers, and you had to click through several notices informing you that this is the case to post this.