# Session Time Out

Tags: asp.net, session, browser, logging, out

I am developing a web site using ASP.Net 3.5 C#. I am listing all the Online users ( users who re logged in on my site) in my site. I want to track and update user's status in Database when a user has logged out or simply closed the browser or navigated to some other site. In all these cases I want to update user's status as "Logged Out".

How can i move forward with it.

Thanks
Vivek

Comment: There is no "user closed browser" event to execute server side code in.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button, you can just handle the click event on the server-side (in code-behind) and then log the status change.

For the case where the browser is closed, you can handle the Session_End event in the global.asax, which fires when the session ends:

```
public void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Fires when the session ends
}
```

Comment: I'm not agree with your answer. Are you sure this would be possible with session modes like SQL Server or State Server? And in the other hand, I've never heard about closing browser would trigger Session.End event...

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer - good point re: the Session_End event.  It does not work in all session modes.  Regarding your second statement, I never said closing a browser would trigger the event.  Session_End will fire when the session ends, which will happen at some point after the browser is closed, or if the browser stays open and the user leaves the site, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Legitimate logout (i.e. Logout by clicking on logout button etc.) can be tracked easily. You just have to handle the event and mark their database status logged out.

However closing the browser is one thing I never had a good success with. You will get many solutions over web which would tell you to capture the close button and then ajax request etc, but I did not have success with any one with that.

(Things like Session_End may come handy but there is a Gotcha that thisevent does not get fired, if you are using anything other than IN-PROC session mode so that's not reliable).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really know if the user has closed the browser or not, or if he navigated to another site. I think you need to use some sort of AJAX control that would send some messages to the server in a given time interval to make sure the user is viewing your site.

Answer (score 0):

First check my answer in this other question:

- [session Handling in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455840/session-handling-in-asp-net/5455943#5455943)

You wouldn't be able to immediately close a session and track this change if some user closes the browser, shutdowns computer or something like that. This is achieved by playing with session timeout.

Another possibility could be consider an user online if it triggered some operation against the server in some time interval, thing that'll be implemented in your server logic.

Logging out should be easly trackable because it's an "human user" action. Just implement a "UserLogout" event in your authentication manager class or any other class handling authentication and track logouts there.

Client-side user actions like browsing to another page or closing Web browser can't be tracked because technology limitations: API lacks in this area. It's more because of Web paradigm and its principles. You'll need to miss that.