# How does PHP manage session?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I initially thought that `php` stores a `session ID` `cookie` and identifies the user based on this cookie. This `cookie` expires as soon as the browser is closed.

I was implementing `remember me` feature, and so I logged in with remember me. Then I closed the browser and opened it again, but it did not login through the cookie I stored, instead, the session variables were still holding the login information. This is seems very strange.

So the question is, how do these `session variables` still persist even after the browser is closed and opened again?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is most of the time browser dependent. Some browsers like latest version of IE, no such problem is seen. After closing of browser, all session variables are destroyed. But in Google Chrome it doesn't happen.

Moreover, session variables are URL sensitive. If you created session on URL say **http://www.example.com** then these session variables are restricted to this specific address only. If you open your page with this URL **http://example.com** then you will see that there are no session variables this time though the destination is same for both the pages. So keep in mind to redirect your page as according to the URL you used to store session variables. For more related information on session variable problems, visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429246/session-variables-in-google-chrome-persist-after-browser-closes)